# C# ListView with a ProgressBar

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to add a progress bar into a sub item of a listview with WinForms. If not, can any controls can be put into the sub items of a listview?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this article titled '[A Much easier to use Listview](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx)' on CodeProject. I have had much more success with '[XPTable](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/XPTable.aspx)' also on CodeProject.