# Is there a way to make a loading bar (progress bar) for ListView?

Tags: winforms, listview, progress-bar, vb.net-2010

I've been planning to make a `ProgressBar` for my `ListView` to know how many percent is already loaded. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Public Class Form1

     Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
            ProgressBar1.Value += 2
            If ProgressBar1.Value >= 100 Then
                ProgressBar1.Value = 100
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
            ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: try to place that in your question and add some more details :)

Comment: done, theres my simple codes, after I've done running it and see the result, I was wondering if I can use it for my program that I'm currently working on

Comment: opo,.  just wait for some other expert about to your problem, but i guess that this is not easy task :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467133/c-sharp-listview-with-a-progressbar

Comment: I see the link, and I think it's not easy...

Comment: english tayo dito dre `:D` http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Comment: ok sir I will try my best :)

Comment: i thought this question is like the `ListViewItems` with a `ProgressBar` i will provide a example, but i can't promise `:D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you will probably want to set the progressbar value in the code where you load the listview instead of the timer tick event, since you don't know how much time it will take beforehand. Hopefully, you can get a rough percentage of the listview that has been loaded, then assign that value to `ProgressBar1.Value`.

Comment: can you help me how to make it sir xpda?

Comment: Just move the code inside your timer1_click function to the code where you load the listview values. Instead of incrementing by two, set it to the percentage that the listview is loaded.

Comment: but sir xpda, someone ask me before about the size of the DB that I'm using and I said it's quite large it's about 188k(rows), so are you telling me that I need to have the percentage of that?

Comment: If you are loading all that into a listview, then yes. But that sounds like too many records to go into a listview.

Comment: it only happens if I need to see all the records but I can filter it, and by that it reduce the rows that are displaying to my listview, so how can I do it the 'loading process'?

Comment: If you know the number of records before you load them, then you can assign the percentage. If you have no way of knowing, then the progress bar won't be able to finish at the same time as the loading process. So, if you just want to show movemement with the progress bar, you could set the progress bar back to zero whever it reaches the maximum, then keep incrementing it. In this case, you could use the timer, although it is less conventional.

Comment: sir xpda could you give me a codes for that? because I really don't know how to start with it.

Comment: Check some more examples on the internet. (I see that's where your code came from). That should help. There are many tutorials on vb.net you might find useful, too. ( http://www.cs.iusb.edu/internship/papers/pmichelbrink/VisualStack.pdf )

Comment: maybe your right, but thanks anyway about the idea on what to do about the record numbers. Thanks sir!