# How to embed ProgressBar into a ListView without WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, progress-bar

All internet sources I've found claim that in `WinForms` the only possibility to achieve this is to create your own `UserControl` (examples: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8580b0d5-bce4-4c49-86cd-9744cacf021c/embeding-progressbar-in-listview), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9188/Embedding-Controls-in-a-ListView), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467133/c-sharp-listview-with-a-progressbar), [and here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView)).

Is it possible to achieve this using only provided `WinForms` controls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

- Create an `ImageList` and add a `Bitmap` to it for each item in a list
- Create a `ListView` and attach the `ImageList` created above as a `SmallImageList`
- Set `ListView` style to `Details`
- Add as much columns as needed  - the first one must contain the picture
- Add subsequent `ListViewItem`s with appropriate strings for each column and appropriate `ImageIndex` referencing appropriate `Bitmap` created in first step

```
//...
{
  foreach (/*item to add to list*/)
  {
    Bitmap progressBarBitmap = new Bitmap(
        this.imageList.ImageSize.Width,
        this.imageList.ImageSize.Height);
    this.imageList.Images.Add(progressBarBitmap);
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
    progressBar.MinimumSize = this.imageList.ImageSize;
    progressBar.MaximumSize = this.imageList.ImageSize;
    progressBar.Size = this.imageList.ImageSize;

    // probably create also some BackgroundWorker here with information about
    // this particular progressBar

    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(
        new[] { "column1", ... },
        this.listView.Items.Count);

    lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = true;
    this.listView.Items.Add(lvi);
    lvi.Tag = /* some convenient info class to refer back to related objects */
  }
//...
}
```

- To refresh the `ProgressBar`:

```
int previousProgress = progressBar.Value;
progressBar.Value = ...
if (progressBar.Value != previousProgress)
{
  progressBar.DrawToBitmap(progressBarBitmap, bounds);
  progressBarImageList.Images[index] = progressBarBitmap;
}
```

where `progressBarBitmap` is the image for the appropriate position (`index`) in `progressBarImageList` for the appropriate `progressBar` (each `ListViewItem` has it's own `ProgressBar` assigned, of course).

**The key thing is to assign the same image again into the same place in `ImageList` - this causes a repaint, and without this it doesn't work.**

Pros:
Quick (not having to write your own `UserControl`), cheap (there was much investigation to find out about this, but not much code to write eventually), and works

Cons:
I've noticed some flickering when there is a large number of items. Also, there are some refreshing issues on Mono.

Example result:
[image]

Code with an example application: https://github.com/bartoszkp/dotrl (BSD license) - in particular see the `BatchExperimentWindow` class: https://github.com/bartoszkp/dotrl/blob/master/Application/BatchExperimentWindow.cs